# Solving a system of equations $x^2 +y^2 −z(x+y)=2,y^2 +z^2 −x(y+z)=4,z^2 +x^2 −y(z+x)=8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to solve the following system over $\Bbb R$:

> $\begin{cases}{x^2 +y^2 −z(x+y)=2\\ y^2 +z^2 −x(y+z)=4\\ z^2 +x^2 −y(z+x)=8}\end{cases}$

Adding all the equations gives $2(x^2+y^2+z^2-xz-yz-xy)=14$. This doesn't look like $(x+y+z)^2$… Do you have some hints?

Comment: Have you tried subtracting?

Comment: @iamvegan: thank you. For instance $(1)$-$(2)$ gives $(x-z)(x+z+y)=-2$, and I also get $(y-x)(y+x+z)=-4 ; (y-z)(y+z+x)=-6$.

Comment: Computing the $S$-polynomials from the three polynomials gives $y^2-1=0,z+2y=0,x+y=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: wow, this is a smart method! But could you explain how this works? I don't know what $S$-polynomials are.

Comment: For some examples see [here](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~whitty/LSBU/MathsStudyGroup/Buchberger.pdf), section $4$. Of course, for algebra-precalculus this is not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2(x^2+y^2+z^2-xz-yz-xy)=((x-y)^2 +(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2)$$
Subtracting first two equation give 
$$(z-x)(x+y+z)=2$$
Similarly develop other relation.
$$\left(\frac{4}{(x+y+z)^2}+\frac{16}{(x+y+z)^2}+\frac{36}{(x+y+z)^2}\right)=14$$

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't see the first one! Thank you. Then I can try $(z-x)/(y-x)=2/(-4)$ (provided that $x+y+z≠0$) and so on. I will try, thanks!

Comment: I loved the trick that gives $(x-y)^2 +(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2$ (+1)